# Как вывести видео в галерее Carbon Fields?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста как вставить видео в галерее Carbon Fields. С картинками всё получается, а видео не выводится. Код прилагается:

```
<?php
use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;

Container::make( 'post_meta', 'Дополнительные поля' )
->show_on_page(7)
->add_tab( 'Отзывы', [
Field::make( 'text', 'responce-title', 'Заголовок' ),
Field::make( 'media_gallery', 'crb_media_gallery', 'Видео отзывы' )
->set_type( array( 'video' ) ),
]);


<?php $slides=carbon_get_post_meta($page_id, 'crb_media_gallery');
 foreach ($slides as $slide):
 $video_src= wp_get_attachment_image_url($slide, 'full');
?>
<div>
 <video controls class="video__item">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo  $video_src; ?>">
 </video>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: вы пробовали создать поле с видео через `Field::make( 'html')`?

Comment: Попробовал. Поле создаётся, а вывести не получается.